# How to view huge text file via Vi or gedit

Tags: text-editor

I have generated a `wordlist.txt` of 11 GB by `crunch-3.6`. When I try to open the file with Vi or gedit, I run into problems because of the file size. How can I view this file?

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. Although its closely related and some answers might be helpful, this one is about viewing and not editing. The accepted answer is not helpful for viewing.

Comment: I agree. Viewing a file and editing a file are not the same thing, and the distinction only becomes more important when the file is very large.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Don't use a text *editor* for *viewing* text.

There are better tools:

---

View files with `less` (Scroll with Space, End, Home, PageUp, PageDown; Search with "/something" ; Leave with q).

From `less` manual:

> Less does not have to read the entire input file before starting, so with large input files it starts up faster than text editors like vi (1).

Usage:

```bash
less wordlist.txt
```

Consider the use of `less -n`:

> -n or --line-numbers:
>
> Suppresses line numbers. The default (to use line numbers) may cause less to run more slowly in some cases, especially with a very large input file.  Suppressing line numbers  with  the `-n` option  will avoid this problem.

(thanks for suggesting -n option @pipe)

---

Use `grep` to get only the lines you're interested in:

```bash
# Show all Lines beginning with A:
grep "^A:"  wordlist.txt

# Show all Lines ending with x and use less for better viewing
grep "x$"  wordlist.txt | less
```

---

Use `head` or `tail` to get the first or last n lines

```bash
head wordlist.txt
tail -n 200 wordlist.txt
```

For editing text, refer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28847/text-editor-to-edit-large-4-3-gb-plain-text-file).

Comment: Note that `more` will load the whole file in memory, unlike `less`. If it's that big, I'd advise against using it. The best option would definitely be to use `grep`.

Comment: I removed `more` as it does not really add any benefit compared to less

Comment: My comment might actually be false. I started checking both `more` and `less` source code, and both seem to use either `open` or `fopen`, which doesn't change anything regarding the way the file is loaded, as far as I know

Comment: Agreed. `more` is a very dated utility, if `less` is available I don't think of any reason why you'd use `more`.

Comment: @Nepho, `more` has one huge advantage over `less`: it doesn't support the `LESSOPEN` input preprocessor.  If you're trying to view the raw text of a man page or something, it's much faster to type `more my_docs.man` than to dig through the `less` documentation to figure out how to suppress the preprocessor.

Comment: I suggest invoking _less_ using something like `less -nS` for huge files, to speed things up a little.

Comment: thanks@ pipe. I added -n, but didn't find information on why -S should provide better performance.

Answer (score 11):

Often, just "grep" is enough to find what you need.

If you need more "context" around a particular line, then use "grep -n" to find the *line numbers* of the lines of interest, then use sed to print out a "chunk" of the file *around* that line:

```
$ grep -n 'word' file 
123:A line with with word in it 

$ sed -n '120,125p' file 
A line 
Another line
The line before
A line with with word in it 
The line after
Something else
```

Comment: no need for sed, you can use `grep -B` and `-A`  to print lines **B**efore and **A**fter ...

Comment: @RoVo Or `-C` for a **C**hunk (both before and after).