# Can not open syslog

Tags: ubuntu-mate, syslog

The first command works, but geany can not open syslog?
I am the owner of the copied syslog.

Why is that? The file is only 1.4 Mb.

```
cp /var/log/syslog /home/andy/Downloads/syslog.txt
geany /home/andy/Downloads/syslog.txt
#rm /home/andy/Downloads/syslog.txt
```

When geany tries to open it, it just opens a untitled file.

Comment: do you have any error messages? are you running it as user `andy`? probably a permission issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Text editor to edit large (4.3 GB) plain text file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28847/text-editor-to-edit-large-4-3-gb-plain-text-file)

Comment: @Cagri Yes, I am running as andy.

Comment: @karel I could not find any editor that was not very difficult to use and exit.

Comment: From the first sentence of the accepted answer to the linked question: "Another method is to use `split`. Split the file into 8 pieces and manipulate the files with an editor."

Comment: @karel I have found split to be very useful.

Comment: @fixit7 If the above link answered your question please click the "Yes" option to the right of "Does this answer your question?" in the light blue banner above your question.

Comment: @karel Sorry I accidentally answered no.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139082/discussion-between-fixit7-and-karel).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than spend a long time finding an editor to open a large file, I went with this. The last 1000 lines of syslog are enough to meet my needs.

```
 cd /home/andy/Downloads
    tail -n 1000 /var/log/syslog > syslog.txt
    geany syslog.txt
    rm syslog.txt
```