# Ubuntu Randomly Started Adding ^M (CRLF) to line breaks (all editors)

Tags: text-processing, file-format

When I do normal line breaks using enter key on my Ubuntu 18 (Virtualbox), it always appeared fine in git - it never added ^M (which I learned is a version of a carriage return/line feed used by DOS). It randomly started adding them to my line breaks and I have no idea why and can't find a solution to get rid of them again.

Another helpful bit of info is that all existing edited line breaks do not show the ^M, only newly edited ones.

Editors tried: gedit, Visual Studio Code, Vim (CLI)

This is what git diff shows:

```
         </div>
     </form>
</div>
</div>^M
<!--^M
 <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
     <li>
         <a href="#">
```

Comment: does this fix it: https://askubuntu.com/a/385297/15811 ?  Use the command line option

Comment: Can you narrow down "all editors"? in which specific editors (CLI? GUI?) have you observed this behavior?

Comment: @steeldriver - I've used vim via command line, I used gedit, I used visual studio code. All of them had the same results, so I figured it had to be an Ubuntu system issue. I ruled out a git config issue because I'd figure all of the other line breaks would now be showing up too.

Comment: @Rinzwind I saw that before posting, but that seems to apply to specific editors, doesn't it? I've ruled out that it is a specific editor issue/config setting.

Comment: yes.that would be gedit. Thing is: you do NOT want to look at the editors you open a file with. You want to look at the one that created the file and how the file got transported. When you create a file in windows it will have a ^M. When you ftp/ssh that file the ^M gets nuked (as we do not use ^M on Linux)

Comment: @Rinzwind I concur. I tested with multiple editors by going to a spot in code without the ^M and added a line break to confirm that each editor all did the same thing, hence my assumption that it's a system thing.